# Prevent any database changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I am working on production ruby console. I need only get some data, not change. But sometimes, if I use '=' instead of '==', I change records. If any suggestions for disable any changes (may by all database commits) when I start to work only with analyzing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
rails c ––sandbox
```

Look more information: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but is that a totally safe way, if the console crashes or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could create another database user with only `SELECT` rights to the db.
Then in your `database.yml` file add a line with that user.
Create an empty  `config/environments/analyzing.rb` file for this environment.

```
analyzing:
  username: your_user
  password: your_pass
```

And then access the console with `rails c analyzing`